# Mysqlclient cannot install via pip, cannot find pkg-config name in Ubuntu

Tags: pip, mysql-python, ubuntu-22.04, libmysqlclient

I'm new to linux and VM's in general. Im currently trying to install mysqlclient on a clean Ubuntu Jammy 64 (22.4) vbox instance. The following commands are run beforehand:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository universe
    sudo apt-get install net-tools -y
    sudo apt-get install python3 -y
    sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
    pip install pkgconfig
    sudo apt-get install pkg-config -y
```

When I try to run `pip install mysqlclient` I get the following error:

```
vagrant@Ctrl-A-EES:~$ pip install mysqlclient
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mariadb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 154, in <module>
          ext_options = get_config_posix(get_options())
        File "setup.py", line 48, in get_config_posix
          pkg_name = find_package_name()
        File "setup.py", line 27, in find_package_name
          raise Exception(
      Exception: Can not find valid pkg-config name.
      Specify MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS env vars manually
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Any suggestions would help greatly! Thanks!

Expected install to resolve without issue. Tried to resolve pkg-config dependency, to no avail.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential`

Comment: Wow, that was fast. It worked, thank you!

Comment: worked for me as well. can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Thank you for your question.  I found this from a similar problem with mysqlclient but it was your package installs that gave me the solution.

Comment: If the issue persists, you might need to set the MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS and MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS environment variables manually before running the pip install command. You can do this in the terminal:

```export MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/mysql

export MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Solution from FlyingTeller:

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential`

Fixed the dependency.

Comment: I needed to also install `pkg-config`.

Comment: `sudo apt install pkg-config` was necessary

Answer (score 50):

In my case `sudo apt install pkg-config` was enough to run `pip install mysqlclient`.

Comment: I needed this only on ubuntu 22 and never on 20

Answer (score 7):

The error you are encountering while trying to install `mysqlclient` using pip3 is related to missing `pkg-config` and its inability to find the required dependencies for building the package.

`pkg-config` fails to find `mysqlclient` and `mariadb` libraries, which are needed to build the `mysqlclient` Python package.

Try these solutions:

1. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev`

If the above doesn't work:

2. you can try installing the mysqlclient library by specifying the paths to the `MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS` and `MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS` environment variables manually, as suggested in the error message.

`sudo MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/mysql" MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient" pip3 install mysqlclient`

NOTE: Replace `/usr/include/mysql` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` with the correct paths to the `mysqlclient` headers and library files on your system if they are located elsewhere. The provided paths are common for Ubuntu-based systems.

Comment: It works for me but before that I have search and get path using ```sudo find / -name libmysqlclient.so``` for ```MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS``` and ```sudo find / -name mysql.h``` for  ```MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS```

Answer (score 7):

use this for Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc libmysqlclient-dev python3-dev
```

use this for Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install gcc mysql-devel python3-devel
```

then run again

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to add `build-essential` and `pkg-config` to my Dockerfile after upgrading to Python 3.11 from 3.8 and the `mysqlclient` install started to fail with the same error. This is working for me now.

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.11-slim as build
...
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install pkg-config -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
...
```

Comment: Your `RUN` commands should be merged into one line to avoid cache issues. E.g. `apt-get update && apt-get install -y pkg-config python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential default-libmysqlclient-dev && pip install mysqlclient`. See https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/instructions/#run

Answer (score 1):

For Rocky 9 the following did the trick:

```
dnf group install "Development Tools"
dnf install python3-devel mysql-devel pkgconfig

pip install mysql-connector mysqlclient
```

https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient

Comment: In my case mysql-connector was missing. After installing both packages (mysql-connector mysqlclient) in the system and inside the python environment all worked out (Ubuntu 22.04). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you guys can try this

```
sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?