# `pip install mysqlclient` fails because `pkg-config --exists mysqlclient` fails

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to `pip install mysqlclient` on Ubuntu 22.04 but get

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.2.0.tar.gz (89 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
      Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
      Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 127.
      Trying pkg-config --exists mariadb
```

As per the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76585758/mysqlclient-cannot-install-via-pip-cannot-find-pkg-config-name) I did

```
apt-get -y install python3-dev gcc build-essential libmysqlclient-dev
```

note that `ls /usr/include/mysql/` and `ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.*` show that libmysqlclient is installed and mysql headers are in place.

What else is missing?

Comment: Tried the most upvoted answer for the linked question?

Comment: As I already said in the question: yes.

Comment: In the question you showed code from the accepted answer, not from the most upvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

```
MYSQLCLIENT_CFLAGS="-I/usr/include/mysql"
MYSQLCLIENT_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmysqlclient"
```

worked for me, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76801424/458742).